# Align items in ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I've created a listView with several objects to show in each of its rows, but I'm having trouble trying to align them altogether [due to the names of each column varying in length and messing the alignment up a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBHmG.png). Is there any way to get them aligned perfectly no matter which name those columns have or something? Here's the code to the method I'm using, thanks in advance, cheers.

```
private void addLayer(String nom){ //Crea capa con nombre por defecto
    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.setSpacing(80);
    ListCell<Text> cell1 = new ListCell();
    Text id = new Text(Integer.toString(rows.size() + 1));

    hb.setMargin(id, new Insets(0,0,0,10));
    hb.getChildren().add(cell1);

    Text name = new Text(nom);
    hb.getChildren().add(name);

    TextField young = new TextField();
    young.setPrefWidth(90);
    Utils.makeNumeric(young);
    hb.setMargin(young,new Insets(0,0,0,30));
    hb.getChildren().add(young);

    TextField esp = new TextField();
    esp.setPrefWidth(90);
    Utils.makeNumeric(esp);
    hb.getChildren().add(esp);

    rows.add(hb);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a `ListView` as a `TableView`, so why not just use `TableView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have data aligned, I recommend using the tableView or TreetableView, as the listview as the name suggests, shows lists, with joined ordering in ascending and descending order.